# Getting different order by native query in JPA repository then sql query

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

My jpa query is

```
@Query(value="SELECT area FROM hoardings WHERE area LIKE %?1% GROUP by area order by instr(area, ?1)", nativeQuery=true)
    public List<String> searchByArea(String area);
```

it's not giving the same order as my sql query is

```
SELECT area FROM 'hoardings' WHERE 'area' LIKE '%n%' GROUP by area order by instr(area, 'n')
```

i think JPA native query doesnt support order by with parameter passed. Is there another way to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: What is the sql that spring is producing for this query - is it the same as your query? Also shouldnt your JPA be '%?1%' not %?1%?

Comment: Hibernate: SELECT area FROM hoardings WHERE area LIKE ? GROUP by area order by instr(area, ?)

Comment: Change to SELECT area FROM hoardings WHERE area LIKE ?1 GROUP by area order by instr(area, ?1)  and pass the %% in the area String, also rename the second param as area2 - it might be confusing spring data

Comment: after this '%?1' spring understand this as string not parameter, here is spring produces query.

Comment: Thanks @farrellmr. Its works now

Comment: cheers - can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Change to -

```
@Query(value="SELECT area FROM hoardings WHERE area LIKE %:area% GROUP by area order by instr(area, :area)", nativeQuery=true)
public List<String> searchByArea(String area);
```

Comment: I also passed the '%' with area. Like String area = "%"+area+"%". Not added % in sql. And its worked now